# How can i get the yesterday date in Oracle when the value of te date from specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to get yesterday date from my Date column,

My logic is

```
SELECT MY_DATE,NAME,MONEY FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_DATE-1
```

My records looks like this

```
MYDATE      NAME    MONEY
10/31/2019  BILLY   2000
11/1/2019   BILLY   3000
```

If today is 11/1/2019, i wanted to get the records on 10/31/2019.
The output of the select i wanted is

```
MYDATE       NAME   MONEY
10/31/2019   BILLY  2000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want yesterday's date, I don't understand why you don't want to use `SYSDATE`.
Otherwise, it's quite easy:

```
WHERE my_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1);
```

Comment: So it can't be using like this (my_date-1) ?

Comment: `my_date` is the value of a column. You want a reference to the current date.

Comment: By the way, you need to `TRUNC` the sysdate in order to eliminate the time part.

Comment: Okay the HH:MM:SS part? But if i wanted the reference from the MYDATE column is it also using
TRUNC(MYDATE-1)?

Comment: What's the type of the column `my_date`? I suppose `DATE`. In case its time part is already 0, you don't need to trunc it.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle a `DATE` data type always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. Your user interface may not show the time components but they still exist.

If your time components are guaranteed to always be set to midnight then you can use:

```sql
SELECT MY_DATE,
       NAME,
       MONEY
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  MY_DATE = TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1;
```

If you have non-midnight time values in the `MY_DATE` column then above method will not work and, instead, the best method is to compare on a range of values (since this allows Oracle to use an index on your column):

```sql
SELECT MY_DATE,
       NAME,
       MONEY
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  MY_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1
AND    MY_DATE <  TRUNC( SYSDATE );
```

You could also truncate both sides of the comparison (however, Oracle would not use an index on the column and would need a separate function-based index):

```sql
SELECT MY_DATE,
       NAME,
       MONEY
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  TRUNC( MY_DATE ) = TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1;
```